Zeros of L function
If $\chi$ is imprimitive character mod $q$, we know that there exists a primitive character $\chi^*$ (mod $q^*$) which induces the character $\chi$ (mod $q$). Then we have
$$L(s,\chi) = L(s,\chi^*) \prod_{\substack{p\mid q \\ p\nmid q^*}} \biggl( 1 - \frac{\chi^*(p)}{p^s} \biggr). $$
For each prime $p$ dividing $q$ but not $q^*$, we have zeros of $L(s,\chi)$ of the form $s = it$ for $t = (\arg\chi^*(p)+2\pi n)/\log p$ for all integers $n$. Could someone please tell me what are all the zeros on the imaginary axis? Are there any other except the ones mentioned?

First of all, there may not be any such $p$, since every prime factor of $q$ might divide $q*$, in which case $L(s,\chi) = L(s,\chi^*)$.  This happens, for instance, when $\chi$ is the character mod $8$ such that $\chi(1) = \chi(5) = 1$, $\chi(3) = \chi(7) = -1$. This $\chi$ comes from the nontrivial character $\chi^*$ mod $4$.
The only zeros of $L(s,\chi)$ on the imaginary axis besides the ones coming from the finite product over $p$ on the right side are zeros of $L(s,\chi^*)$.  It turns out that the $L$-function of a primitive Dirichlet character (like your $\chi^*$) has no zeros on the imaginary axis except for a simple zero at $s = 0$ when the character is even and nontrivial. So  you'll have no extra zeros besides the ones you described unless $\chi^*$ is even and nontrivial, in which case you get an extra zero at $s = 0$.  Note the other factors may have already contributed a zero at $s = 0$, namely when $\chi^*(p) = 1$ at some $p$ dividing $q$ but not $q^*$.
